# Подскажите, как грамотнее?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотнее: "приятного прочтения" или "приятного чтения"? Или оба варианта равноправны?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Прочтение это процесс вместе с его завершением. Тогда "Приятного прочтения" могло бы значить получение в целом положительных эмоций от всей книги. Но то же самое обычно имеют в виду и под "приятным чтением", лишь растянутое во времени. Хотя слух режет "приятного прочтения". Иногда слишком грамотные фразы режут слух)

Comment: Спасибо большое за комментарий!

Comment: Второе, оно звучит нейтральнее, немного плавнее и культурнее. И не факт, что человек намерен читать до конца.

Comment: Большое спасибо за комментарий!